# Load balancer scaling

Tags: aws-api-gateway, load-balancing, api-gateway, azure-load-balancer, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am quite new to the load balancing scenarios expecially in cloud. We are using load balancers to avoid load to a particular server and to avoid single point of failure . But then how does the load balancer itself scale . Isn't it a single point of failure ? Say, We have 1000 connections from client and we distribute it to to 4 servers using load balancer equally ,Then each server handle 250 connections . But the load balancer need to handle all 1000. Then, how do we avoid single point of failure or distribute load across machines?. I know that load balancer may not require to do as much processing required by the application server, since it does not do any functional processing. But still, there are modern load balancers which does lot of functionalities like SSL offload, intelligent routing etc. How does this work in Modern Highly scalable scenarios where we need to handle millions of connections?.

Comment: It's the cloud. You can consider a Load Balancer as a 'black box' that simply works. It is the job of the cloud provider to ensure that is scales and works as necessary.

Comment: Google search for documents like this one: https://sre.google/workbook/managing-load/ and this one: https://sre.google/sre-book/load-balancing-frontend/

Answer (score -1):

One way you can run multiple load balances is using [DNS load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

DNS load balancing relies on the fact that most clients use the first IP address they receive for a domain. In most Linux distributions, DNS by default sends the list of IP addresses in a different order each time it responds to a new client, using the round‑robin method. As a result, different clients direct their requests to different servers, effectively distributing the load across the server group.

Any better ways are appreciated.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)